# What can go wrong if I do not use an async context manager inside an async function?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

It is possible for me to use use context managers inside asynchronous functions, for example,

```
async def main():
    with open("Hello.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Test123")

asyncio.run(main())
```

However, I did notice that some people utilize `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` context managers when dealing with context managers inside asynchronous functions. So far I could not provide an example where not utilizing an asynchronous context manager would result in problems. So my question is simply, how dangerous is it to not be using an asynchronous context manager inside an async function?

Comment: There’s nothing dangerous about calling synchronous functions inside asynchronous ones. The worst that can happen is your asynchronous function blocks the event loop while the synchronous code runs and your program slows down. Using your example, if you’re opening a small local file, that probably isn’t going to be an issue. If you’re opening a large file mounted from a networked device, however, you’d probably want to stream that asynchronously to let other tasks have a chance to run.